# file get content from iframe

Tags: php, iframe, dom, web-crawler

I would like to get content of a iframe with id or class of that iframe.

```
$links = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Book-Secret-Wisdom-Prophetic-Evolution/dp/599054314X/ref=pd_sbs_14_2/257-3608675-7951114?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=599054314X&pd_rd_r=f103ccc1-7985-11e9-987c-178a1a538946&pd_rd_w=E5xsZ&pd_rd_wg=206kw&pf_rd_p=18edf98b-139a-41ee-bb40-d725dd59d1d3&pf_rd_r=MV7NZ41V278ECZM1135G&psc=1&refRID=MV7NZ41V278ECZM1135G";

$res = @file_get_contents($links);

$dom = new DomDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($res);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

I would like to get content by id:

```
$dom->getElementById('iframeContent');
```

However, it alway return a page, not content of that iframe.

Anyone meet that problem?, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes don't have content (well, they might, but it is alternative content for when iframes are not supported by the client).

They have a `src` attribute containing a URL pointing at an external document.

You need to read the `src` attribute value, resolve it to an absolute URL (if it isn't one already), then make an HTTP request to it, parse that, and extract the data from it.